# Mozilla Sops fails to decrypt when triggered from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mozilla-sops

I'm trying to use SOPS to decrypt a file using Jenkins, using this command:

```
sops -k -d  mysecret.yaml > out
```

But then I get this output and it waits till forever:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

I've tried to export some env. vars, but I ended up with the same result

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
```

Can anyone please explain to me why that happens?

**Update:**

By using `sops -k -d mysecret.yaml --output OUT` with the above env. vars and now I can see file being decrypted but still vim process is not finish and the task stays forever.

Answer (score 2):

I shouldn't use `-k`  as a command argument after removing KMS ARN and replacing it with `export SOPS_KMS_ARN="arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxxx:key/xxx-xxxx-xxxxx"`

Correct command is:

```
    export SOPS_KMS_ARN="arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxxx:key/xxx-xxxx-xxxxx
    sops  -d rsi-tls-cert.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```